# Create a df for each list of lists within a list of lists of lists

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, for-loop

I have a list of lists of lists and another list

```
lslsls = [[[1,2,3],[11,12,13],[21,22,23],[1,2,3],[11,12,13],[21,22,23]],[[1,2,3],[11,12,13],[21,22,23],[1,2,3],[11,12,13],[21,22,23]],[[1,2,3],[11,12,13],[21,22,23],[1,2,3],[11,12,13],[21,22,23]]]

ls = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

I wish to create a pandas dataframe of each list of lists within "lslsls", and when i do so add each element of "ls" to each row the dataframe. I can do this individually i.e.

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame(lslsls[0])
df["name"] = ls[0]
```

However I need to loop through all list of lists within "lslsls", and add the elements from ls as a column as I go through. This will create 3 separate df, ideally I could name them as each element in "ls"

So ultimately end up with:

```
import pandas as pd    
a = pd.DataFrame(lslsls[0])
a["name"] = ls[0]
b = pd.DataFrame(lslsls[1])
b["name"] = ls[1]
c = pd.DataFrame(lslsls[2])
c["name"] = ls[2]
```

This is my attempt:

```
for i in ls:
    for p in lslsls:
        i = pd.DataFrame(lslsls[p])
        i["name"] = ls[i]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use a dict comprehension to create your dataframes within a collection by zipping the two iterables.

then we can chain `assign` to create your column.

```
dfs = { Name : pd.DataFrame(each_list).assign(name=Name) 
               for Name,each_list in zip(ls,lslsls) } 

print(dfs['a'])

    0   1   2 name
0   1   2   3    a
1  11  12  13    a
2  21  22  23    a
3   1   2   3    a
4  11  12  13    a
5  21  22  23    a
```

---

```
print(dfs['b'])

    0   1   2 name
0   1   2   3    b
1  11  12  13    b
2  21  22  23    b
3   1   2   3    b
4  11  12  13    b
5  21  22  23    b
```

If you want a single dataframe we can use `pd.concat`

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(each_list).assign(name=Name) 
                for Name,each_list in zip(ls,lslsls)])

print(df)
    0   1   2 name
0   1   2   3    a
1  11  12  13    a
2  21  22  23    a
3   1   2   3    a
4  11  12  13    a
5  21  22  23    a
0   1   2   3    b
1  11  12  13    b
2  21  22  23    b
3   1   2   3    b
4  11  12  13    b
5  21  22  23    b
0   1   2   3    c
1  11  12  13    c
2  21  22  23    c
3   1   2   3    c
4  11  12  13    c
5  21  22  23    c
```

Answer (score 3):

**One approach**

#### [`numpy.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) and [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)

```
#import numpy as np
(pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(lslsls),
              index=np.repeat(ls, tuple(map(len, lslsls))))
   .rename_axis('Name').reset_index())


   Name   0   1   2
0     a   1   2   3
1     a  11  12  13
2     a  21  22  23
3     a   1   2   3
4     a  11  12  13
5     a  21  22  23
6     b   1   2   3
7     b  11  12  13
8     b  21  22  23
9     b   1   2   3
10    b  11  12  13
11    b  21  22  23
12    c   1   2   3
13    c  11  12  13
14    c  21  22  23
15    c   1   2   3
16    c  11  12  13
17    c  21  22  23
```

Or

```
(pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(lslsls))
   .assign(Name=np.repeat(ls, tuple(map(len, lslsls)))))


     0   1   2 Name
0    1   2   3    a
1   11  12  13    a
2   21  22  23    a
3    1   2   3    a
4   11  12  13    a
5   21  22  23    a
6    1   2   3    b
7   11  12  13    b
8   21  22  23    b
9    1   2   3    b
10  11  12  13    b
11  21  22  23    b
12   1   2   3    c
13  11  12  13    c
14  21  22  23    c
15   1   2   3    c
16  11  12  13    c
17  21  22  23    c
```

---

```
%%timeit
pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(lslsls)).assign(Name=np.repeat(ls, tuple(map(len, lslsls))))
914 µs ± 84.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
(pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(lslsls),
              index=np.repeat(ls, tuple(map(len, lslsls))))
   .rename_axis('Name').reset_index())
1.23 ms ± 12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)


%%timeit
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(each_list).assign(name=Name) 
                for Name,each_list in zip(ls,lslsls)])
4.49 ms ± 105 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Awesome, I really need to refractor my core python code with numpy methods, so much performance to be gained!

Comment: We all forget to go down to numpy sometime :) @Datanovice

Comment: Another play on your lovely solution, while avoiding ``assign`` : ```df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(lslsls));
df.insert(0, "Name", np.repeat(ls, len(lslsls[0])))```